# How do I auto-scroll to a specific table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an html page with a header, a table containing 100 items and a footer.

When there is a search, I highlight the row containing the data.

However, if the highlighted row is row 75, the user has to scroll down to find it.

How can I automatically scroll to that row?

I did see [scrollTo()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp) but see it only takes axis points.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

(Using cgi in C, html, css and javascript/jquery)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use `scrollIntoView()`. (It's on the DOM elements directly.)

Be aware that there are some layout situations where scrolling something on the page can cause IE6 and 7 to decide that random other stuff needs to be scrolled too.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
<script>
function ScrollToElement(theElement){

  var selectedPosX = 0;
  var selectedPosY = 0;

  while(theElement != null){
    selectedPosX += theElement.offsetLeft;
    selectedPosY += theElement.offsetTop;
    theElement = theElement.offsetParent;
  }

 window.scrollTo(selectedPosX,selectedPosY);

}
</script>

<body onload="ScrollToElement(document.formName.elementName)">
```

Comment: i have edited my answer because after testing i found it wont work

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this:

Use this line where ever you like,

```
<a id="bookmark"></a>
```

and when you start your page, call it like this:

```
http://mypage.com/setting.php#bookmark
```

That worked for me without showing the anchor.

Check again for using bookmark in html

EDITED:
Check: [JavaScript - Jump to anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694686/javascript-jump-to-anchor)

Comment: the question isnt about jumping to an anchor. its about scrolling a table.