# JavaScript - Jump to anchor

Tags: javascript, anchor

I'm trying to open a div with a jump to the anchor. The opening part is working but it's not jumping to the named anchor

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function spoil(id){
        if (document.getElementById) {
            var divid = document.getElementById(id);
            divid.style.display = (divid.style.display = 'block');
            window.location = '#' + id;
        }
    }
</script>

<a href="http://example.com" onclick="spoil('thanks');" title="hello">
    <img src="images/gfx.png" alt="world" width="300" height="300"/>
</a>
```

Any ideas what's wrong with it?
Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like you're unhiding a spoiler div. If so, you can scroll the element into view as follows:

```
function spoil(id) {
    var divid = document.getElementById(id);
    divid.style.display = 'block';
    divid.scrollIntoView(true);
    return false;
}
...
<a href="#" onclick="return spoil('thanks');" title="hello"><img src="images/gfx.png" alt="world" width="300" height="300"/></a>
```

Answer (score 54):

Did you try `window.location.hash = '#'+id;`?