# window.location.href not working when href is same page

Tags: javascript, cfml

I have an input form which takes parameters for a report.  I submit these to the same page. When the report is generated I would like to move the user to the top of the report.  However, javascript is not going to the anchor.  When my href is a different but otherwise identical page the anchor works, but when it is the same page it does not.  Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function moveto() {
window.location.href = "frag6.cfm#betty";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script type = "text/javascript">
moveto()
</script>
<cfset subtest = ArrayNew(1)>
<cfloop from = "1" to = "10" index = "m">
<cfloop from = "1" to = "3" index = "i">
<cfloop from = "1" to = "4" index = "j">
<cfset test[i][j] = "#m#_#i#_#j#">
</cfloop>
</cfloop>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var = "#test#">
<cfloop from = "1" to = "3" index = "i">
<cfloop from = "1" to = "4" index = "j">
<cfset subtest[j] = test[i][j]>
</cfloop>

<cfdump var = "#subtest#">
</cfloop>
<a name = "betty"> here I am </a>
```

Comment: try location.href.hash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694686/javascript-jump-to-anchor

Comment: tried it before posting question -- did not work for me

Answer (score 1):

You should use **id** attribute for anchors instead of name and **location.hash** instead of location.href

```
<div id="happyanchor"></div>

<script>
function goToAnchor(anchor){
    location.hash = anchor;
}

goToAnchor('happyanchor');
</script>
```